# Select value and next highest value from rows in same table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
LowerPoints MessageTemplate
0           zero
10          ten
100         hundred
```

and I would like to select from it so I have a list of `lowerPoints` and then the NEXT lowest value of `LowerPoints`

e.g.

```
select
    low.LowerPoints As LowerPoints
    , high.LowerPoints as UpperPoints
    , low.MessageTemplate as MessageTemplate
from MessageTemplate low
    , MessageTemplate high
where high.LowerPoints = (select top 1 LowerPoints from MessageTemplate where LowerPoints > low.LowerPoints order by LowerPoints)
```

which returns

```
LowerPoints UpperPoints MessageTemplate
0           10          zero
10          100         ten
```

but I cannot see how to get the third value and give it a "null" value for `UpperPoints`. i.e. the last row would be

```
100                     hundred
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of the outdated syntax, separating tables by comma  would be read as INNER JOIN.
You could write it as:

```
select
    low.LowerPoints As LowerPoints
    , high.LowerPoints as UpperPoints
    , low.MessageTemplate as MessageTemplate
from MessageTemplate low
LEFT JOIN MessageTemplate high
ON high.LowerPoints = (select top 1 LowerPoints from MessageTemplate where LowerPoints > low.LowerPoints order by LowerPoints)
```

You might also use a simple subselect

```
Declare @a Table (LowerPoints int, MessageTemplate varchar(30))
insert into @a Values(0,'zero'),(10,'ten'),(100,'hundred')

Select a.LowerPoints
     ,(Select top 1 LowerPoints from @a b 
       where b.LowerPoints>a.LowerPoints
       order by b.LowerPoints) as UpperPoints
     ,a.MessageTemplate
from @a a
Order by LowerPoints
```

or a CTE generating a defined row number (rn) with a LEFT JOIN to itself for the condition b.rn = a.rn + 1

```
;With CTE as
(
Select LowerPoints,MessageTemplate
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by LowerPoints) as rn
from @a a
)
Select c1.LowerPoints
      ,c2.LowerPoints as UpperPoints
      ,c1.MessageTemplate 
from CTE c1
LEFT JOIN CTE c2 on c2.rn=c1.rn +1 
Order by c1.LowerPoints
```

Comment: Thank you...went for the left join

Comment: @Vasily If it was the same time there is no need to delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
--create temp table   
 IF object_id('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #test
    CREATE TABLE #test  (LowerPoint INT,MessageTemplate VARCHAR(10))
    INSERT INTO #test VALUES (0 ,'Zero'), (10,'ten'), (100,'hundred');
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    WITH cte
    AS (SELECT *,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY LowerPoint) AS RN
        FROM #test)

    SELECT a.LowerPoint
        ,b.LowerPoint AS UpperPoints
        ,a.MessageTemplate
    FROM cte a
    LEFT JOIN cte b
        ON (a.rn + 1) = b.rn
```